# Perl regex subsitute last occurrence

Tags: regex, perl, non-greedy

I have this input:

```
AB2.HYNN.KABCDSEG.L000.G0001V00
AB2.HYNN.GABCDSEG.L000.G0005V00
```

I would like to remove all which finish by `GXXXXVXX` in the string.

When i use this code:

```
$result  =~ s/\.G.*V.*$//g;
print "$result \n";
```

The result is :

```
AB2.HYNN.KABCDSEG.L000
AB2.HYNN
```

It seems each time the regex find `".G"` it removes with blank .
I don't understand.

I would like to have this:

```
AB2.HYNN.KABCDSEG.L000
AB2.HYNN.GABCDSEG.L000
```

How i can do this in regex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

After talking in the comments, the final solution was:

```
s/\.G\w+V\w+$//;
```

In your regex:

```
s/\.G.*V.*$//g;
```

those `.*` are greedy and will match as much as possible. The only requirement you have is that there must be a `V` after the `.G` somewhere, so it will truncate the string from the first `.G` it finds, as long as it is followed by a `V`. There is no need for the `/g` modifier here, because any match that occurs will delete the rest of the string. Unless you have newlines, because `.` does not match newlines without the `/s` modifier.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it works only if there was number between G and V and after V. How the regex can work if there is no only numbers ?

Comment: @Patrick Then you'll have to be more specific in your requirements. You can use `\.G...V..$` to match 3 and 2 wildcard characters. You can use `.G.{0,3}V{0,2}$` to match 0 to 3 and 0 to 2 wildcard characters. Since you don't mention what kind of characters can be there, I cannot tell you how to match them.

Comment: For example this : AB2.HYNN.GABCDVEG.L000.GA1CDV6I
in the expression GXXXXVXX, XX can  be numeric or alphabetic ?

Comment: I suggest leading with the thing that works and explaining the broken one after. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result =~ s/\.G\d+V\d+//g;
```

Works on given input.